# Getting messages "dius/pact_broker docker image is deprecated" in Pact broker browser

Tags: pact, pact-broker

I am using PAct broker docker image and Postgres docker image for my PAct broker. Until last week it was working fine. Today I have deleted the pack broker docker container and images and downloaded it fresh from dius/pact-broker. after that I am started getting one red message in the HAL browser like "The dius/pact_broker docker image is deprecated. Please use the new dius/pact-broker image."[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBlGU.jpg)

Is there some change in the Pact broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, stop using pact_broker and use the pact-broker image instead...